# Session variable not matching database table variable

Tags: php, sql, session, pdo

I am trying to display the value for this: `$supoints = $_SESSION['upoints'];`. But the value being displayed on the page does not match up with the value on the database.

This is my index.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'dbpdo.php';
$sid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$supoints = $_SESSION['upoints'];
?>
<h3>index.php page</h3>
<?php echo $supoints; ?>
<form action="pointshand.php" method="post">
    <input name="buycshamt">
    <button type="submit" name="buyptsbut">Buy</button>
</form>
```

All the form does is submit the value of `<input name="buycshamt">` to my database table column `upoints`. My database table `users` looks like this:

```
userid | username | upass | upoints
   1   |  user1   | pass1 |  100
```

It will not match up because when the user first logs in, the value for `$supoints` is `100`, HOWEVER, when the user inputs a new value for `<input name="buycshamt">`, like `300`, and submits that, this new value will be updated on the table `users` but NOT on the variable `$supoints`. `$supoints` will remain as `100` on the webpage, but on the table it will successfully update to 100+300, which equals `400` (which is the number that *should* be displayed on the webpage. What is causing this behavior that prevents the updating of the value for 
`$supoints`?

This is my pointshand.php that inserts the input value to my database table:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'dbpdo.php';
if(isset($_POST['buyptsbut'])) {
    $buycshamt = $_POST['buycshamt'];
    $sid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users2 SET upoints=upoints+? WHERE userid=?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $buycshamt);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $sid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt = null;
    header('Location: index.php'); exit();
}
$pdo = null;
?>
```

And this is my signinhand.php that logs the user in with the session variables:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    require 'dbpdo.php';
    $useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if (!empty($useremail) || !empty($password)) {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT userid, username, upoints, upass FROM users2 WHERE username=?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $useremail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $sid = $row['userid'];
            $sname = $row['username'];
            $supoints = $row['upoints'];
            $supass = $row['upass'];
        }
        $stmt = null;
        $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $supass);
        if ($pwdCheck == true) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['userid'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['upoints'] = $row['upoints'];
            header("Location: index.php?login=success");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
$pdo = null;
?>
```

Comment: When you do the update, you will also need to set the new value into `$_SESSION`. To do so, you'll need to select the new value

Comment: @Phil I thought session variables automatically update upon change (or after page refresh)? So shouldn't this line `$supoints = $_SESSION['upoints'];` automatically update to reflect the new value from the database once the page refreshes?

Comment: Look at where you're assigning a value to `$_SESSION['upoints']`. It only happens once during login. It will not maintain a connection to your DB and update when the data changes there. When you handle the form submission and update the DB, you will also need to assign a new session value, eg `$_SESSION['upoints'] = $newValue;`

Comment: @Phil I'm still a little confused. So does that mean I should add this line `$_SESSION['upoints'] = $supoints;` after this line `$_SESSION['upoints'] = $row['upoints'];` on my signinhand.php page, or do I change this line `$supoints = $_SESSION['upoints'];` to this line `$_SESSION['upoints'] = $supoints;` on my index.php page?

Comment: No. **When you update the DB data** (in `pointshand.php`) is when you would assign a new value into the session. Something like `$_SESSION['upoints'] += $buycshamt;` though if you want to be extra safe, you would query the database after the `UPDATE` and set the session value from the retrieved data.

Comment: @Phil ok so on my pointshand.php, I changed my the UPDATE statement to `UPDATE users2 SET upoints=?+? WHERE userid=?` and added this line below it `$stmt->bindParam(1, $supoints);` but I'm still seeing no changes. The variable still remains the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value in session to stay in sync with the database, you'll need to update both at the same time.

This would be done in your `pointshand.php` file where you handle the form submit and DB update. This is best done in a transaction to avoid race conditions on your data. For example

```php
$buycshamt = $_POST['buycshamt'];
$sid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$pdo->beginTransaction();
try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users2 SET upoints = upoints + ? WHERE userid = ?');
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $buycshamt, PDO::PARAM_INT); // make sure it's handled as an int
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $sid);
    $stmt->execute();

    // fetch the updated value
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT upoints FROM users2 WHERE userid = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$sid]);
    $_SESSION['upoints'] = $stmt->fetchColumn(); // update the value in the session
    $pdo->commit();

    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $pdo->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: huh.. I didn't think session variables needed to be selected again. I kept thinking they updated automatically on page reload. Otherwise, thanks for fixing my code and thoroughly specifying where to correct my mistakes. Much appreciated!